# Customizable Table Columns in Apache Isis

Tags: apache, isis

I am creating an application with Apache Isis and everything is rendered correctly except that rendered tables are showing all properties from my model.

Is there a quick way to allow users to choose which columns they want to show on the table and preferably in which order?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It's a bit hacky, but you can provide an implementation of [`TableColumnOrderService`](http://isis.apache.org/guides/rgsvc/rgsvc.html#_rgsvc_presentation-layer-spi_TableColumnOrderServicehttp://isis.apache.org/guides/rgsvc/rgsvc.html#_rgsvc_presentation-layer-spi_TableColumnOrderService)

Comment: But, isn't that to order and/or hide on the code level. I need something to let users on the UI layer to configure for each table inside application.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't read your question carefully enough.

I'm afraid the answer to that is "no", not out of the box.  You would need create an alternative implementation of the table component.  

Take a look at CollectionContentsAsAjaxTablePanel and its factory, CollectionContentsAsAjaxTablePanelFactory, for a starting point.

Also the docs, http://isis.apache.org/versions/1.16.2/guides/ugvw/ugvw.html#_ugvw_extending_replacing-page-elements